# Angular 2 Post request return 404 from service

Tags: angular, http-post

I'm create a page for login, but have a problem with a post request.
I'm use final version Angular 2

**login.html**

```
<label for="username">User</label>
<input type="text" id="user" #user>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" #password>
<button type="submit" (click)="onLogin(user.value, password.value); user.value=''; password.value=''">Login</button>
```

**login.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'login',
templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
providers: [ LoginService ],
styleUrls: [ 'css/login.css' ]
})
export class Login extends Locale {
users: User[];

constructor(public localization: LocalizationService,
            private _loginService: LoginService) {
    super(null, localization);
}

  onLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    if (!username && !password){return;}
    this._loginService.login(username, password)
        .subscribe(
            user  => this.users.push(user),
            error =>  console.log(error),
            () => console.log("Complete")
        );
  }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public username: string,
    public password: string) {}
}
```

**user.servece.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
// URL to web api
private loginUrl = './authenticate';

constructor (private http: Http) {}

login (username, password ): Observable<User> {
    var body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log("Url: "+this.loginUrl);
    console.log("body: " + body);
    console.log("headers: "+headers);

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}

private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

I have error:
POST http://localhost:3000/authenticate 404 (Not Found)

The data must be transmitted entered and stored in a json-file that would be when linking localhost:3000/authenticate.

What's wrong, please help!

Comment: The server doesn't accept connections at this URL+port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting data  to http://localhost:3000/authenticate  which okay. you did not have any code to that accept any post day. You should have REST service  for http://localhost:3000/authenticate that consumes your data. Please see how to develop REST  Service for your desired language.

Comment: I'm don't create /authenticate page, it must be created in my java Servlet API, but I'm not understand how it must be implemente

Comment: you can test http://localhost:3000/authenticate using post-man chrome plugin. Using post man plugin you can POST, GET, PUT and DELETE http request.  Check your api using http method, if it works then try with code.

Comment: that's means using chrome plugins your api is worked well right?. if yes then you have to use chrome browser developer tool that look into the network tab. see what are request it is send during the post request. if you get error about "Cross-Origin" then you have to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Thank's for your answer. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RIrdFfy9t4 after watch this video, I'm understend where was my problem